# libvirt live migrate error, cannot open file

Tags: migration, centos, qemu, kvm, libvirt

I want to use live migration for a vps guest from one host to another. I use KVM with raw disk format for vps guests. Here's the command:

```
virsh migrate --live guest09 qemu+ssh://123.45.6.78/system
```

But I receive an error message

```
error: cannot open file '/dev/volumeGroup/guest09': No such file or directory
```

What's the correct way to do live migration with libvirt?

Answer (score 0):

You probably do not have shared storage setup between the hosts, i.e. NFS or sshfs. Apparently, shared storage is assumed in most of the examples. You can see some examples in http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/QA:Testcase_Live_Migration_using_libvirt/virsh

Alternatively, you could try the `--copy-storage-all` option

```
virsh migrate --live --copy-storage-all guest09 qemu+ssh://123.45.6.78/system
```

but this still requires that the filename path is exactly the same, and the files/devices have been created beforehand.
To be honest, I haven't been able to get it to work without quirks.

Comment: I still receive the same error message after adding the option --copy-storage-all